# How to force creating a new session in Keycloak to authenticate CLI apps using OIDC Protocol

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I have a webapp that uses Keycloak for user management and auth provider successfully.

The same application requires a CLI tool for some operations (similar to the `gcloud` CLI + web console).

I've implemented the CLI part using the OIDC Authorization Code Flow that opens the browser for the user to authenticate. It works like a charm.

However, if the user logoff from the browser, Keycloak will invalidate the session and the `cli` will have to re-authenticate to get a new access_token and refresh_token.

My question here is, how can I force the CLI app login to create a new session separate from the browser session.

Or, if not possible, what's the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: Create another IDP session = use different browser/anonymous window/...  Or perform logout and then immediately login (so current IDP session will be terminated)

Comment: The problem is that it has to work seamlessly for the users. Opening on a anonymous browser is not a user friendly option. I’ve used other tools that have a similar flow but don’t have this problem, not sure what is the issue.

Comment: OIDC Authorization Code Flow for CLI is very hackish aproach, so don't expect any seamless solution with good user experience.

Comment: Yeah, I am kinda getting it now, but I chose it as I thought it was the way to go. What is the correct approach for this kind of need?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe `OAuth 2.0 Device Authorization Grant`. It will be worth to check which flow is used by `gcloud`.

Comment: Thanks, @JanGaraj . The Device Auth was also a non-option on my case as it requires a code to be copied/pasted and would also be not as user-friendly as needed. Eventually found out the correct way to do, and it can be done with the Authorization Code Flow. Ended up being a pretty simple solution. See my answer for more details. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, found out that I just have to add the scope `offline_access` to the list of scopes I am requesting. Keycloak will then create a new offline session (bad name for the feature, Offline just means that the user doesn't have to be present, but all the refreshes happen the same way)

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/server_admin/topics/sessions/offline.adoc